# XSD for same tag different attribute names

Tags: xml, xsd

I have weird scenario with xml and want to validate it using xsd.
below is the xml

```
<tag1>
   <tag2 attribute1="value1" />
   <tag2 attribute2="value2" />
<tag1>
```

and below is the xsd I am using

```
<xs:element name="tag1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="tag2">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="attribute1" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
          <xs:attribute name="attribute2" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

everything works fine if tag2 has both or any of attribute1 or attribute2.
but my scenario is if there is no tag2 with attribute1 as below

```
<tag1>
   <tag2 attribute2="value2" />
<tag1>
```

it should be considered invalid, however

```
<tag1>
   <tag2 attribute1="valueX" />
<tag1>
```

is valid.

Is there any way an XSD can be built that validates this scenario?

Comment: Years ago, you have asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/327162/1987598) - and several answers have been put forward. Please [accept one of them or otherwise react to them](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Agree with @MathiasMüller that you should accept/react to past answers and that this question is a bit unclear.   If every `tag2` must have an `attribute1`, then see [Mathias' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30108121/290085).   If you're saying that there must be at least one `tag2` present that has an `attribute1`, you'll need XSD 1.1 to express such a constraint.  Let us know if XSD 1.1 is an option for you.

Comment: cannot use XSD 1.1 :( so I guess I have to validate it through code

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand, but why not simply state that the use of `attribute1` is required, instead of optional?

```
 <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="tag2">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="attribute1" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="attribute2" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

Then, a `tag2` element without an `attribute1` attribute will be considered invalid.

Comment: this cannot be done as it implies tag2 should always contain the attribute1 but it need not. your solution works perfectly for the below scenario <tag1><tag2 attribute1="value" /><tag2 attribute1="value" attribute2="value" /></tag1> but you see the 2nd tag2 need not (or should not) have attribute1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what rules you want to impose, but the general rule in XSD 1.0 is that if two sibling elements have the same name, then they must have the same type (that is, you cannot apply different validation rules to two sibling elements with the same name).

In XSD 1.1, of course, you can get around this with assertions.